# Different behavior between neo4j-gremlin-bolt , Tinkergraph and Neo4j-gremlin

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop3, neo4j-bolt

I am seeing different behavior between Tinkergraph and Neo4j-gremlin from the  neo4j-gremlin-bolt Neo4j implementation of Tinkerpop3, specifically in this bit of code:

```
// different Tinkerpop impls
Graph graph = new Neo4JGraph(driver, vertexIdProvider, edgeIdProvider);
// Graph graph = Neo4jGraph.open("C:\\tmp\neo");
// Graph graph = TinkerGraph.open();

GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();

String label = "Person";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println("Before " + +g.V().toList().size());
  graph.addVertex(label);
  System.out.println("After " + +g.V().toList().size());
}

// if graph is transactional
 graph.tx().commit();
```

What I expected was that the vertex count increments from 1 to 10 which is what I see for Tinkergraph and Neo4j-gremlin. What I see with neo4j-gremlin-bolt is that the count is always 1 (after the first AddVertex). After the commit, 10 instances appear in the Neo4J db (as expected). Running it a second time, the count is always 11 (after the first addVertex) and 20 instances appear after the commit.

The only way I have gotten this to work as expected with neo4j-gremlin-bolt is to commit() and close() the graph after every addVertex, which doesn't seem right.

This seems like fundamental behavior, so I assume I am missing something obvious.

neo4j-gremlin-bolt - v0.2.18

tinkergraph-gremlin - v3.2.4

neo4j-gremlin - v3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a bug in neo4j-gremlin-bolt's handing of transient objects:
https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt/issues/52

Fix expected shortly.